# Can I create a function to replace the object on which it is called?

Tags: javascript

When some new JSON arrives, I just love converting all the string dates to date objects. I would love it even more if I could create a function that would replace the string on which it was called with the parsed date object. Is this possible?

```
String.prototype.hydrateAsDate = ()=>{
    this = new Date(this);
    // what I want to do, but how do I do it ?!
}
```

Comment: You can't change the reference of parent object inside of it. You need to traverse the fields. Just because there could be hundreds of references to this instance.

Comment: No, you can't do that.  You have to `return` the new object instead.

Comment: `this` in arrow functions is the outer context `this`! You probably don't want to use it. Running `[1,2,3].map(()=> this)` in your console will ouput `[Window, Window, Window]`, not `[1,2,3]`

Comment: also, don't forget that `JSON.parse()` allows you to pass an additional function which can mutate values before they're added to the returned object.

Comment: It's gettin very expensive to ask questions round here. I've found this all very interesting and useful, even if no one else seems to like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use revive from `JSON.parse`, it will return `Date` objects instead of strings in result

```js
function revive(key, value) {
 var a;
 if (typeof value === "string") {
  a = /^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}(?:\.\d*)?)Z$/.exec(value);
  if (a) {
   return new Date(Date.UTC(+a[1], +a[2] - 1, +a[3], +a[4], +a[5], +a[6]));
  }
 }
 return value;
}

console.log(JSON.parse("\"2018-05-15T13:40:30.052Z\"", revive) instanceof Date);
```

This example is taken from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json_parse.js

Comment: Oh I like that a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the prototype you might just use an utility:

```
 function parseDates(obj, ...keys) {
   const result = {...obj};
   for(const key of keys)
      result[key] = new Date(obj[key]);
   return result;
 }
```

Which is usable as:

```
parseDates({ createdAt: 123456789 }, "createdAt");
```

Or to replace one:

```
obj = parseDates(obj, "createdAt");
```

Comment: What is that amazing `...` syntax?

Comment: @bb, it's [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).